# Configuration to run Hadoop with HBase

Tags: apache, scala, hadoop, sbt, hbase

I am trying to explore HBase APIs with scala code So I want to setup a simple standalone scala project (using SBT) following references from [here - Official Scala documentation](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#scala). Here is my build.sbt

```
name := "hbase-sandbox"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

resolvers += "Apache HBase" at "https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases"
resolvers += "Thrift" at "http://people.apache.org/~rawson/repo/"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "*" % "2.7.1",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "1.1.2"
)
```

Here is the code mentioned in the documentation

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.{Connection,ConnectionFactory,HBaseAdmin,HTable,Put,Get}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes

object Main extends App {
  val conf = new HBaseConfiguration()
  val connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf)
  val admin = connection.getAdmin()

  // list the tables
  val listtables=admin.listTables()
  listtables.foreach(println)

  // let's insert some data in 'mytable' and get the row

  val table = new HTable(conf, "mytable")

  val theput= new Put(Bytes.toBytes("rowkey1"))

  theput.add(Bytes.toBytes("ids"),Bytes.toBytes("id1"),Bytes.toBytes("one"))
  table.put(theput)

  val theget= new Get(Bytes.toBytes("rowkey1"))
  val result=table.get(theget)
  val value=result.value()
  println(Bytes.toString(value))
}
```

Errors/Exception

```
Error:(1, 8) object HBaseConfiguration is not a member of package org.apache.hadoop.hbase
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
       ^
Error:(3, 8) object Bytes is not a member of package org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
       ^
Error:(6, 18) not found: type HBaseConfiguration
  val conf = new HBaseConfiguration()
                 ^
```

I am unable to download hadoop with hbase. `sbt` is not able to resolve the dependencies. I have tried out various combinations with Hadoop and Hbase versions. Moreover, `org.apache.hbase#hbase~1.1.2` jars does not exist in [apache repository](https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/hbase/hbase/1.1.2/)

If I am not on the right path, what should be the correct way to setup a simple SBT project for experimenting with HBase APIs in scala.

### Update

Same code with same dependency versions work as Maven project So I guess the issue is with some SBT dependency resolver or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation you're linking to, the Ivy dependencies look different than in your code. This is from documentation:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-core" % "0.20.2",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase" % "0.90.4"
)
```

And this is yours:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "*" % "2.7.1",
  "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "1.1.2"
)
```

Besides different revisions numbers, the wildcard in artifact's name is the problem. SBT doesn't support this.